# How to change currency symbol based on user choice

Tags: android

I want to give my users the possibility to choose in the settings what currency symbol they want to use (e.g. € and $). What is the best way to change the symbols in the app according to the setting? So I am able to read out the setting and know in my actvity what symbol the user wants. my way would be to do always a switch or if statement and for each currency symbol to create own text. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to go to change the currency symbol in all my textviews.

i have stored the symbol in sharedpreferences and I can read it from sharedpreferences in each of my activities. Now I have to create for each textview which contains a currency symbol, a if statement?

Is there no possibility to store it somehow in xml and take out the right symbol like it is done with different languages?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way you're implementing your UI (using styles etc.) it shouldn't be a big deal switching between € and $.
As far as I can see it's not a bad thing tough storing the user preferred symbol as a preference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Shared Preferences will be the best approach: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
This is a good tutorial and well explained in my opinion of what the Shared Preferences could do: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/

Simple save the symbol in a Shred Preference value, and the retrieve it when you need it.

Comment: I know about sharedpreferences. The problem I am facing is to change the textviews which contain the symbol